# Pan is the only working thing for OrbitControls

Tags: three.js

I am trying to program a solar system that you can orbit around and pan so I added an OrbitControls to my project and pan is working fine but for some reason rotate and zoom aren't working.  I have tried copying other people's examples and I cannot figure out what is wrong with mine. I don't know if it could just be my computer, but I have no reason to believe that it would be.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Example 01.02 - First Scene</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/stats.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/dat.gui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/chroma.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/dat.gui.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Stats-output">
</div>

<!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
<div id="WebGL-output">
</div>

<!-- Javascript code that runs our Three.js examples -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    // once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
    $(function () {

        var stats = initStats();
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        var clock = new THREE.Clock();
        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = -150;
        camera.position.y = 200;
        camera.position.z = 150;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // create a render and set the size
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
        renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        ccontrols = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        ccontrols.damping = 0.2;
        ccontrols.addEventListener( 'change', render );

        var ambiLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x747474)
        scene.add(ambiLight);

        var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
        pointLight.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        pointLight.distance = 100;
        scene.add(pointLight);

        //create the light box
        var lightboxgeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3000,50,50);
        var lightboxmat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./TexturesAndModels/lightbox.png"), side: THREE.BackSide});
        var lightbox = new THREE.Mesh(lightboxgeom, lightboxmat);

        //sun and glow
        var sun = createMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(20, 20, 20), "texture_sun.jpg", "texture_sun_DISP.jpg", "texture_sun_SPEC.jpg");
        sun.shading = THREE.NoShading;
        var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( 
        { 
            map: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "TexturesAndModels/GLOW.png" ), 
            useScreenCoordinates: false, alignment: THREE.SpriteAlignment.center,
            color: 0xffcc00, transparent: false, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending
        });
        var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
        sprite.scale.set(100, 100, 1.0);
        sun.add(sprite);    

        //mercury
        var mercury = createMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.50, 20, 20), "texture_mercury.jpg", "texture_mercury_DISP.jpg", "texture_mercury_SPEC.jpg", "texture_mercury_NRM.jpg");

        //venus
        var venus = createMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(3.80, 20, 20), "texture_venus_surface.jpg", "texture_venus_surface_DISP.jpg", "texture_venus_surface_SPEC.jpg", "texture_venus_surface_NRM.jpg");

        //earth and clouds
        var earth = createMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(4.00, 20, 20), "ColorMap.jpg", "Bump2.jpg", "SpecMask2.png", "ColorMap_NRM.jpg");

        //mars
        var mars = createMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(2.10, 20, 20), "texture_mars.jpg", "texture_mars_DISP.jpg", "texture_mars_SPEC.jpg", "texture_mars_NRM.jpg");

        //Jupiter
        var jupiter = createMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(18.7, 20, 20), "texture_jupiter.jpg", "texture_jupiter_DISP.jpg", "texture_jupiter_SPEC.jpg", "texture_jupiter_NRM.jpg");

        //saturn
        var saturn = createMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(18, 20, 20), "texture_saturn.jpg", "texture_saturn_DISP.jpg", "texture_saturn_SPEC.jpg", "texture_saturn_NRM.jpg");

        //uranus
        var uranus = createMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 20, 20), "texture_uranus.jpg", "texture_uranus_DISP.jpg", "texture_uranus_SPEC.jpg", "texture_uranus_NRM.jpg");

        //neptune
        var neptune = createMesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(14, 20, 20), "texture_neptune.jpg", "texture_neptune_DISP.jpg", "texture_neptune_SPEC.jpg", "texture_neptune_NRM.jpg");

        // position the planets
        sun.position.x=0;
        sun.position.y=0;
        sun.position.z=0;
        earth.position.y=0;
        mars.position.y=0;
        venus.position.y=0;
        mercury.position.y=0;
        saturn.position.y=0;
        jupiter.position.y=0;
        uranus.position.y=0;
        neptune.position.y=0;

        // add the planets to the scene
        scene.add(lightbox);
        scene.add(earth);
        scene.add(sun);
        scene.add(mercury);
        scene.add(venus);
        scene.add(mars);
        scene.add(jupiter);
        scene.add(saturn);
        scene.add(uranus);
        scene.add(saturn);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        $("#WebGL-output").append(renderer.domElement);

        var r = 0;
        var step = 0;

        var controls = new function() {
            this.timeScale = 1;
        }

        var gui = new dat.GUI();
        gui.add(controls, 'timeScale', 0, 10);

        // render the scene
        render();

        function createMesh(geom, imageFile, bump, spec, normal) {
            var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./TexturesAndModels/" + imageFile)
            var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
            mat.map = texture;

            if (bump) {
                var bump = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./TexturesAndModels/" + bump)
                mat.bumpMap = bump;
                mat.bumpScale = 0.2;
            }

            if(spec) {
                var spec = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./TexturesandModels/" + spec)
                mat.specularMap = spec;
            }

            if(normal) {
                var norm = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./TexturesAndModels/" + normal)
                mat.normalMap = norm;
            }

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
            return mesh;
        }

        function render() {
            stats.update();

            earth.position.x = Math.sin(r*0.1)*150;
            earth.position.z = Math.cos(r*0.1)*150;
            earth.rotation.y = step += controls.timeScale * 0.02;

            mercury.position.x = Math.sin(r*0.4)*58;
            mercury.position.z = Math.cos(r*0.4)*58;
            mercury.rotation.y = step/58.7;

            venus.position.x = Math.sin(r*0.1625)*108;
            venus.position.z = Math.cos(r*0.1625)*108;
            venus.rotation.y = step/243;

            mars.position.x = Math.sin(r*0.05)*228;
            mars.position.z = Math.cos(r*0.05)*228;
            mars.rotation.y = step*1.026;

            jupiter.position.x = Math.sin(r*.008)*483;
            jupiter.position.z = Math.cos(r*.008)*483;
            jupiter.rotation.y = step*2.44;

            saturn.position.x = Math.sin(r*.003)*886;
            saturn.position.z = Math.cos(r*.003)*886;
            saturn.rotation.y = step*2.35;

            uranus.position.x = Math.sin(r*.001)*1784;
            uranus.position.z = Math.cos(r*.001)*1784;
            uranus.rotation.y = step*1.34;

            neptune.position.x = Math.sin(r*.0006)*2794;
            neptune.position.z = Math.cos(r*.0006)*2794;
            neptune.rotation.y = step*1.26;

            r+=controls.timeScale * (Math.PI/180*2);

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }

        function initStats() {

            var stats = new Stats();

            stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms

            // Align top-left
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

            $("#Stats-output").append(stats.domElement);

            return stats;
        }

    });



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing `ccontrols.addEventListener( 'change', render );`

Comment: @WestLangley I tried that and nothing seems to change

Comment: Try 
        `controls.noZoom = false;
  controls.noPan = false;
 controls.enabled = true;`